# Parsing multiple occurrences of an item into a dictionary

Tags: python, string, parsing, dictionary

Attempting to parse several separate image links from JSON data through python, but having some issues drilling down to the right level, due to what I believe is from having a list of strings.

For the majority of the items, I've had success with the below example, pulling back everything I need. Outside of this instance, everything is a 1:1 ratio of keys:values, but for this one, there are multiple values associated with one key.

```
resultsdict['item_name'] = item['attribute_key']
```

I've been adding it all to a resultsdict={}, but am only able to get to the below sample string when I print.

INPUT:

```
for item in data['Item']:
    resultsdict['images'] = item['Variations']['Pictures']
```

OUTPUT (only relevant section):

```
'images': [{u'VariationSpecificPictureSet': [{u'PictureURL': [u'http//imagelink1'], u'VariationSpecificValue': u'color1'}, {u'PictureURL': [u'http//imagelink2'], u'VariationSpecificValue': u'color2'}, {u'PictureURL': [u'http//imagelink3'], u'VariationSpecificValue': u'color3'}, {u'PictureURL': [u'http//imagelink4'], u'VariationSpecificValue': u'color4'}]
```

I feel like I could add `['VariationPictureSet']['PictureURL']` at the end of my initial input, but that throws an error due to the indices not being integers, but strings.

Ideally, I would like to see the output as a simple comma-separated list of just the URLs, as follows:

OUTPUT:

```
'images': http//imagelink1, http//imagelink2, http//imagelink3, http//imagelink4
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you get, because it looks like you got unicode strings, and maybe you need to convert them.

Comment: @uzzee It depends on which input I try. Copying the other areas of the input, I would use...

resultsdict['images'] = items['Variations']['Pictures']['VariationsSpecificPictureSet']['PictureURL']

and get the error: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Ok, maybe try `resultsdict['images'] = items['Variations']['Pictures'][0]['VariationsSpecificPictureSet'][0]['PictureURL']`

Comment: @uzzee That certainly helps, thank you. How would I go about reaching all of the image links meeting that criteria?

Answer (score 0):

An answer to your comment that required a bit of code to it.

When using

```
for item in data['Item']:
    resultsdict['images'] = item['Variations']['Pictures']
```

you get a list with one element, so I recommend using this

```
for item in data['Item']:
    resultsdict['images'] = item['Variations']['Pictures'][0]
```

now you can use

```
for image in resultsdict['images']['VariationsSpecificPictureSet']:
    print(image['PictureUR‌​L'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, @uzzee, it's appreciated. I kept tinkering with it and was able to pull the continuous string of all the image URLs with the following code.

```
resultsdict['images'] = sum([x['PictureURL'] for x in item['variations']['Pictures'][0]['VariationSpecificPictureSet']],[])
```

Without the sum it looks like this and pulls in the whole list of lists...

```
resultsdict['images'] = [x['PictureURL'] for x in item['variations']['Pictures'][0]['VariationSpecificPictureSet']]
```